# Is it possible to apply CSS3Pie border radius to jQuery UI globally?

Tags: jquery-ui, css, css3pie

To apply `behavior: url(PIE.htc);` to all css files in the project seams to be very long story and with each new version i need to repeat it again.

Is there `jquery ui CSS3Pie` versions i can find somewhere?

**OR**

Is it possible to add CSS3Pie support in separate css file, so in such case it will be possible to use that css for any new jquery ui version.

I am trying to do such fix for jquery UI that in my custom css:

```
.ui-corner-top, .ui-corner-left, .ui-corner-right, .ui-corner-bottom { behavior: url("PIE.htc"); }
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-tl, .ui-corner-tr, .ui-corner-bl, .ui-corner-br { behavior: url("PIE.htc"); }
```

But it is not working.

At the same time such fix working for my styles, for example if a have style

```
.mystyle
{
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border: solid 2px #36405c;
}
```

Than i could define this and it will be working:

```
.mystyle
{
  behavior: url("PIE.htc"); /*it will be working*/
}
```

So i am assuming that it is not working in `jquery UI` case because `jquery UI` has multiple places with `.ui-corner-*` declarations with different radiuses.

Anyway is it possible to do something with that?

Any ideas someone?

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own theme with http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/, set all the border-radius to 0 and then apply your styles to ".ui-corner-all"